# How to clear interval placed inside .map callback function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using map method on array in order to set intervals sending requests to API for a given number of times (each timeInterval have different access token). 
Can I somehow create a function that will clear those intervals from outside?

```
await Promise.all(
    this.state.tokens
       .map((token, index) => {
           const driver = setInterval(() => {
               if (decodedPolylines[index].length > 1) {
                   api.sendLocation(
                       token,
                       decodedPolylines[index][0][0].toString(),
                       decodedPolylines[index][0][1].toString()
                   );
               } else {
                   api.clockInOut(
                       token,
                       'out',
                       decodedPolylines[index][0][0].toString(),
                       decodedPolylines[index][0][1].toString()
                   );
                   clearInterval(driver);
               }
           }, 1000);
       })
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function will clear all intervals, but you can also use filter() in case you want only some to be cleared:

```
const drivers = [];

await Promise.all(
    this.state.tokens
       .map((token, index) => {
           const driver = setInterval(() => {
               if (decodedPolylines[index].length > 1) {
                   api.sendLocation(
                       token,
                       decodedPolylines[index][0][0].toString(),
                       decodedPolylines[index][0][1].toString()
                   );
               } else {
                   api.clockInOut(
                       token,
                       'out',
                       decodedPolylines[index][0][0].toString(),
                       decodedPolylines[index][0][1].toString()
                   );
                   clearInterval(driver);
               }
           }, 1000);
           drivers.push(driver);
       })
);

const clearDrivers = () => {
    drivers.forEach(d => clearInterval(d));
};

// call clearDrivers() when you want to stop all intervals
```

Comment: Doesn't work because this Promise is located inside a function and I wanted to clear those intervals from outside of it (I guess your example doesn't work for me because intervals are located in function's local scope). But thanks because you gave me idea how to solve it :D If I can't get variables from inside of the function, I can still insert one inside. So I created a variable that holds a boolean and included it in the first "if". Changing this variable from false to true causes "else" to fire, which causes clearing interval.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return those intervals first to be able to clear all of them:

```js
const intervals = this.state.tokens
   .map((token, index) => setInterval(() => {
      ...
   }, 1000))
);

intervals.forEach(interval => clearInterval(interval));
```

Actually, i can't see any `Promise` in your code, are you sure you need to use `await Promise.all(...)`?